# Sidekiq doesn't process en-queued jobs setup using Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, sidekiq

I am running Sidekiq in my rails application to process background jobs.

sidekiq.yml

```
:verbose: false
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:concurrency: 5
:queues:
  - ["queue1", 1]
  - ["queue2", 1]
  - ["queue3", 1]
  - ["queue4", 1]
  - ["queue5", 1]
  - critical
  - default
  - low
max_retries: 1
```

ps aux | grep sidekiq

```
root        48  0.0  0.0   4400  1264 ?        Ss   13:06   0:00 runsv sidekiq
root     15753  1.0  0.0   4628   924 ?        S    13:14   0:00 /bin/sh /root/app/config/docker/sidekiq.sh
root     15754 35.0  0.0  78136 11408 ?        R    13:14   0:00 ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/bin/sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e qa -L log/sidekiq.log
```

Sidekiq can process the jobs in local environment. But When I deploy in qa environment, sidekiq jobs are added to the queue and not processed.

I am able to see the queues names in redis-cli

What should I do to process the jobs in the queue?

Versions:-

```
sidekiq 5.2.5
Rails 5.2.2
```

initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
redis_config = {
  url: "redis://#{Rails.configuration.redis.fetch('host')}:#{Rails.configuration.redis.fetch('port')}/#{Rails.configuration.redis.fetch('db')}",
  namespace: "myapp"
}

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = redis_config 
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = redis_config
end
```

Comment: I'd bet it's a configuration problem. Sidekiq container is not looking at the right redis.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have added my sidekiq initializers in question. Where do I look for errors and what config file should be checked and updated?

Comment: "`Rails.configuration.redis.fetch('host')`" - looks like it sits in the environment file, `config/environments/staging.rb`.